# I want to call a function when Matrrix element is 1 and I want to go trough the matrix row wise (Python, Numpy)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

So I have a little programm where i want to call a function when the selected Element of the Matrix is 1 but when i execute the Programm it doesn't print out every time the Matrix has 1 as element.
This is my Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Name = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
X = 0
S2 = pd.DataFrame([
             [X, 1, 0, 1, 1],
             [0, X, 1, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, X, 1, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, X, 1],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, X]
             ], index=Name, columns=Name)
I_Max_array = np.zeros((1,200))

def function1():
    Connections = np.zeros((7, 3), dtype=np.object)
    Connections[0][0] = "Connection"
    Connections[0][1] = "Line-Type"
    Connections[0][2] = "I-Max"
    for i in range(0, len(S2)):
        column_name = S2.index[i]
        for j in range (0, i):
            if S2[column_name][j] == 1:
                row_name = S2.dtypes.index[j]
                connection_name = str(row_name) + "-" + str(column_name)
                print("calculate connection " + str(connection_name))
                for time in range(0, I_Max_array.size):
                    I_Max = calculate(time)
            Connections[i+1][2] = I_Max
    return Connections

def calculate(time):
    I_Max = 2*2
    I_Max_array[0][Time] = I_Max
    return I_Max_array

I_Max = function1()
```

The program just prints out 1 Line of where the Matrix is 1 and that is connection A-B, what is also weird is the fact that when i just run the inner Programm of the function1() it seems to get all the valid connections but doesn't save them in the right Connections row

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after the first printout, there is an execution error
and a StackTrace ended with

```
NameError: name 'Time' is not defined
```

Take a look at *calculate* function.
Its parameter is *time*, with **lower** case "t".
But inside this function you have *Time*, with **upper** case "T".

Change *Time* to *time* and your code should execute with no error.